# To create JWT where to provide public key in this implementation

Tags: go, authentication, jwt, token

I see private key, but where to provide the public key so I can publish. Works perfectly but I am missing the public key, where is it given while creating the JWT token? I assume the example key (dnfksdmfksd) below is the private key. I am using github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go Thanks!

```
func CreateToken(userid uint64) (string, error) {
    var err error
     //Creating Access Token
     os.Setenv("ACCESS_SECRET", "jdnfksdmfksd") //this should be in an env file
     atClaims := jwt.MapClaims{}
     atClaims["authorized"] = true
     atClaims["user_id"] = userid
     atClaims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 15).Unix()
     at := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, atClaims)
     token, err := at.SignedString([]byte(os.Getenv("ACCESS_SECRET")))
     if err != nil {
       return "", err
     }
     return token, nil
   }
```

Comment: You are using the wrong signing method for public and private key method. You should use RS256,RS384, or RS512 for RSA and ES256,ES384 or ES512 for ESDCA as a signing method. Private key will be use to sign the the token and public key to validate it.

Comment: Thank you, Any link to such implementation in golang?

Comment: Hope this example will help you - https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/master/http_example_test.go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HS256 is a symmetric algorithm. It uses a shared secret. There is not public/private key. The recipients of the JWT have to use the same secret to validate the signature.

Comment: Sorry, trying to understand. If everyone has access to shared secret, what will stop from someone from generating the jwt tokens and passing them as originals. A hacker or an authority - both can produce exactly same jwt token then, right? [ learning opportunity for me - Haha]

Comment: You wouldn't expose the HS256 key to the public. You either only share it with trusted parties, or you use it to validate if a JWT is signed by you. If you need validation with a public key, you need RS class of signing methods.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. So I as an creator and authority will only be able to verify my own jwt tokens. That will work for me, because I am the only one providing the resources to users. Thanks!